# PCMCIA preventing laptop from booting up

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, sony-vaio, pcmcia

My friend has brought his dead laptop over. It is a Sony Vaio with Windows Vista.

When booting up, it blue screens and reboots.

I have tried to boot up with [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.net/) and this will freeze when starting up PCMCIA. If I start Knoppix with

```
knoppix nopcmcia
```

it disables pcmcia and boots up fine. So I presume there is a problem with the PCMCIA controller on the laptop. My friend does not use any PCMCIA cards, so doesnt really need it.

Is there anyway I can similarly disable PCMCIA so that Windows will boot up fine?